# First ionization energy and electron gain enthalpy of dihydrogen / stability comparison of dihydrogen ions

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, stability, ionization-energy, electron-affinity

Subset of: [How can antibonding orbitals be more antibonding than bonding orbitals are bonding?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4517/108386)

> Stability of $\ce{H2^{-}}<\ce{H2^{+}}<\ce{H2}$

> Stability of $\ce{N2^{-}}<\ce{N2^{+}}<\ce{N2}$

Source: Online lecture Etoosindia.

I am more concerned of $\ce{H2^{-}}<\ce{H2^{+}}$.

Does any satisfactory explanation exists (perhaps which can be generalized) for it? That is to add electron in anti-bonding molecular orbital more difficult than removing electron from bonding molecular orbital?

Observation indicates that First ionization energy of $\ce{H2}$ is greater than electron gain enthalpy (magnitude).

Comment: Yes, that's a general rule that antibonding electrons "more antibonding" than bonding electrons are "bonding".

Comment: @Jay  As Mithoron mentioned, this may help https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4517/how-can-antibonding-orbitals-be-more-antibonding-than-bonding-orbitals-are-bonding